# IE8 Toggle Bug?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, toggle, render

I think I have an issue with IE8 and it's driving me nuts.
let me explain it with images and an online demo.

When you first visit the page it's all normal as you see below

[a http://yasinergul.com/FlashDen/IE8-Toggle-Bug-Demo/image/a.jpg](http://yasinergul.com/FlashDen/IE8-Toggle-Bug-Demo/image/a.jpg)

Then when you click to the "Click here to add new one" button.. it displays a div that includes a form... untill now it still works fine as you see below...

[b http://yasinergul.com/FlashDen/IE8-Toggle-Bug-Demo/image/b.jpg](http://yasinergul.com/FlashDen/IE8-Toggle-Bug-Demo/image/b.jpg)

When you click to "Cancel" button it hides form... but this time "Some text here" part collapse to the gree box above..

[c http://yasinergul.com/FlashDen/IE8-Toggle-Bug-Demo/image/c.jpg](http://yasinergul.com/FlashDen/IE8-Toggle-Bug-Demo/image/c.jpg)

But when you try to select any text on the page or click any empty space on the page, "Some text here" returns back to normal position...

And the weird thing is, since there is a toggle function on the link you can also close form with "Click here to add new one" link and when you close form by clicking the "Click here to add new one" link it works fine...

I have also tried to use show(), hide() methods or addClass() , removeClass() with a class that includes "display:none"... I also tried toggleClass(), but no luck...

I think this is about rendering engine of IE8 but may be you HTML-CSS-jQuery gurus out there may know a workaround...

http://yasinergul.com/FlashDen/IE8-Toggle-Bug-Demo/

Best regards,
PDesignX

Comment: Not sure of the reason, but something else that is interesting. If you use the IE8 Developer Tools and delete the hidden class from the #box-add div (before you click on the Add link), then the "Click here to add new one" link displays the problem and clicking "Cancel" works correctly.

Comment: yes i also noticed it... so it's not about being inside the the div that is being shown or hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

removing margin-bottom of the inf-box and adding padding to the div that contains "Some text here" solved the problem... it's said that this is a "collapsing margin" issue...

you can find a detailed description about it here

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=CollapsingMargin